# Erro ao criar Diagramas no SQLServer Studio 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Esta semana tive um problema na criação de diagramas no meu banco de dados ( SQL Server 2014), ele me retornava uma mensagem de erro:

> Database diagram support objects cannot be installed because this
>   database does not have a valid owner.  To continue, first use the
>   Files page of the Database Properties dialog box or the ALTER
>   AUTHORIZATION statement to set the database owner to a valid login,
>   then add the database diagram support objects.

E outra mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma solução?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2043693/4319922](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2043693/4319922)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viva, você é o Dono da BD?
O problema pode estar relacionado com o facto de você ser ou não o Owner.

Tente fazer Detach e Attach da BD.